# Suppose $f(x)$ monotonous decreases on $[0,+\infty) $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(x)$ monotonous decreases on $[0,+\infty) $ and $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) \text dx=0 $$
Then, proof that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) $ converges if and only if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\text dx $converges.

Actually I listed an inequality and almost thought it has been solved without the condition $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) \text dx=0$$
that is 
$$f(k)=\int_{k-1}^{k}f(k)\text dx\le\int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)\text dx\le\int_{k-1}^{k}f(k-1)\text dx=f(k-1) $$
then we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(k) \le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)\text dx \le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(k-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(k) $$
So if  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) $ converges, then $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^{k}f(x)\text dx=\int_{1}^{\infty }f(x)\text dx$ converges. So is $\int_{0}^{\infty }f(x)\text dx$.
Also, if $\int_{0}^{\infty }f(x)\text dx$ converges, then $\int_{1}^{\infty }f(x)\text dx$ converges. Thus $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(k)$ converges.

With the process, I think I have solved this without the condition $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) \text dx=0 $. But since this a question from a serious exam I am not so sure about my proof. So anyone could help confirm or show some more ways to proof this?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=0$.

Comment: @Riemann That doesn't change the fact that, in order to prove that the series converges if and only if the integral converges, you don't need the hypothesis that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: How did you justify your claims that if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges then $\displaystyle \int \limits_1^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ converges and the converse?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is right. The fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ is irrelevant for the proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(k)$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ converges. Of course, when they converge, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.